# Calculate item's quantity in one table SQL Server (SUM Outstanding of items)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sum

I would ask question about sum in SQL Server.

I have a table that stores orders like this:

```
    Code     |    items    |    Kinds      |   Qty  |
-------------+-------------+---------------+--------+
PUR/2004/001 |    b001     |    PURCHASE   |   5    |
PUR/2004/001 |    b002     |    PURCHASE   |   10   |
PUR/2004/002 |    b001     |    PURCHASE   |   3    |
REC/2004/001 |    b001     |    RECEIVE    |   4    |
```

What I need is a query to calculate the remaining outstanding of every item on the table.

The result I want is like this:

```
    items    |  Outstanding Order  |
-------------+---------------------+
    b001     |          4          |
    b002     |          10         |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit different way of conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    items,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Kinds = 'PURCHASE' THEN Qty
             WHEN Kinds = 'RECEIVE'  THEN -Qty
        END) AS [Outstanding Order]

FROM Table1
GROUP BY
    items;
```

RESULT:

```
items   Outstanding Order
b001    4
b002    10
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bc4b2/2)

Comment: I tried the query and it works perfectly and solved my problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

We can use conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    items,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Kinds = 'PURCHASE' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN Kinds = 'RECEIVE' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS [Outstanding Order]
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    items;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo